I'm migrating saml2 from springboot 3. An error occurs in the service provider's Saml2MetadataFilter. Has the format changed?

i am try
Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(                (RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver) relyingPartyRegistrationResolver,
new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
or
Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(
(RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository) relyingPartyRegistrationResolver,
new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
but
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entityId cannot be null or empty
